# Simple If statement seemingly not working, but JS console does not log any errors

Tags: javascript, if-statement

A very basic If statement that I have used before in other templates is not working for some reason, and I am at a loss.  The function is as part of a navigation bar where the pages slide in and out of view.  I have four nav buttons: Home, Designs, Contact, Testimonials.  Here is the problem code:

```
var currentPage = 1;

function openDesigns() {
    document.getElementById("homePage").style.left = "-" + 620 + "px";
    document.getElementById("designsPage").style.left = "-" + 620 + "px";
    document.getElementById("contactPage").style.left = "-" + 620 + "px";
    document.getElementById("testimonialsPage").style.left = "-" + 620 + "px";
    document.getElementById("homeButton").style.height = "50px";
    document.getElementById("homeButton").style.lineHeight = "40px";
    document.getElementById("designsButton").style.height = "60px";
    document.getElementById("designsButton").style.lineHeight = "57px";
    document.getElementById("contactButton").style.height = "50px";
    document.getElementById("contactButton").style.lineHeight = "40px";
    document.getElementById("testimonialsButton").style.height = "50px";
    document.getElementById("testimonialsButton").style.lineHeight = "40px";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("homePage").style.zIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById("designsPage").style.zIndex = 1;
        document.getElementById("contactPage").style.zIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById("testimonialsPage").style.zIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById("designsPage").style.left = "-" + 0 + "px";
    }, 250);
}

document.getElementById("designsButton").onclick = function() {
    if (currentPage == 1 || 3 || 4) {
        openDesigns();  
        currentPage = 2;
        console.log(currentPage);
    } else if (currentPage == 2) {
        console.log("yup"); //this is here to check whether or not the code was getting to this point
    }
}
```

This is just one set of four funcions (one per page).  The currentPage variable is supposed to represent which page is currently open (Home being 1, Designs being 2).  When the Designs nav button is clicked, it should check to see if that page is already open.  It works fine if it isn't (it opens the page as it should), but the problem is that once the page is open, currentPage is set to 2 and so next time the button is clicked, it should trigger the "else if" statement where nothing happens...but instead, it triggers the "if" statement AGAIN, which triggers the opening animation again, which I do not want.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening.  I thought the code was rock solid...I've done this many times before.  Any ideas?

Comment: `currentPage == 1 || 3 || 4` is not doing what you think, it is interpreted as `currentPage == 1 || true || true` so is always true. I think you want `currentPage == 1 || currentPage == 3 || currentPage == 4`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
if (currentPage == 1 || 3 || 4) {
```

To this:

```
if (currentPage == 1 || currentPage == 3 || currentPage == 4) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition as follows

```
document.getElementById("designsButton").onclick = function() {
    if (currentPage === 1 || currentPage === 3 || currentPage === 4) {
        openDesigns();  
        currentPage = 2;
        console.log(currentPage);
    } else if (currentPage == 2) {
        console.log("yup"); //this is here to check whether or not the code was getting to this point
    }
}
```